# Angular4 : Failed to compile: Argument type {path: string, component HomeComponent}[] is not assignable to parameter type Routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to set up routing for the first time on Angular 4:

[image]

My app.module.ts code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { MembersComponent } from './members/members.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    MembersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
        path: 'member',
        component: 'MembersComponent'
    },
    {
        path: 'product',
        component: 'ProductComponent'
    }
    ])

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I get the error:

> Argument of type '{ path: string; component: string; }[]' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'Route[]'.   Type '{ path: string;
>   component: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
>       Types of property 'component' are incompatible.
>         Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Type'.

Comment: Please remove ' ' quotes just add MembersComponent in the component property

Comment: Components are used as string but it supposed to be a type of component. You have to remember you are using typescript and it understands type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route is defined like this:

```
export interface Route {
    path?: string;
    component?: Type<any>;
```

where `Type` is defined like this:

```
export declare const Type: FunctionConstructor;
```

So you have to specify reference to the component class (which is a function constructor) in the route definition, not string:

```
component: 'MembersComponent' <---------- should be component class reference
```

So import `MembersComponent` and put it like this:

```
import { MembersComponent } from '...' 
...
    RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
        path: 'member',
        component: MembersComponent
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

> JUST FOR REFERENCE

After making change in the component class i got this error
[image]

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { MembersComponent } from './members/members.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    MembersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
        path: 'member',
        component: MembersComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'product',
        component: ProductComponent
    }
    ])

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**SOLUTION:**

[REFERENCE LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464062/unexpected-value-decoratorfactory-imported-by-the-module-tempmodule)

Comment: remove NgModule from imports. and also you have not specified for root path .. that is path: ' '. Please specify what component should load for  root component