# Unexpected value 'DecoratorFactory' imported by the module 'AppModule' in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I am trying to start an Angular / Kendo UI project but the browser gives me the following error in the console:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'DecoratorFactory' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

(there's no error in the CLI while compiling, only at runtime)

This is my `app.module.ts` file:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TabModule } from 'angular-tabs-component';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpClientJsonpModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NotificationModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-notification';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { LayoutModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
import { ToolBarModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar';
import { DialogModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';
import { EditService } from './edit.service';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { GridEditFormComponent } from './edit-form.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, AppRoutingModule, TabModule, HttpClientModule, HttpClientJsonpModule, FormsModule, GridModule, NotificationModule,
    Injectable, LayoutModule, ToolBarModule, DialogModule, EditService, ReactiveFormsModule, GridEditFormComponent ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

I needed to import `NgModule`, else the `@NgModule` interface declaration gives me this error:

```
Cannot find name 'NgModule'. Did you mean 'module'?
```

Note: this is **not** a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464062/unexpected-value-decoratorfactory-imported-by-the-module-tempmodule) (I followed the instructions but that didn't fix the error).