# Angular 11: core.js:1141 Uncaught Error: Type DecoratorFactory does not have 'ɵmod' property. at getNgModuleDef (core.js:1141:15)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

The project (Angular 11, rxjs, material, @swimlane/ngxdatatabe) can be build and serve with no error message.
When loading the landing page from Chrome, it is stuck and console shows the following error:

```
core.js:1141 Uncaught Error: Type DecoratorFactory does not have 'ɵmod' property.
    at getNgModuleDef (core.js:1141:15)
    at recurse (core.js:25270:21)
    at recurse (core.js:25281:17)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:25266:5)
    at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:25380:13)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:28993:27)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:29239:16)
    at Module.zUnb (main.ts:10:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79:1)
    at Object.0 (home.component.ts:18:27)
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "GRIDDASH",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "11.2.14",
    "@cds/core": "5.0.0",
    "@clr/angular": "5.5.3",
    "@clr/icons": "12.0.12",
    "@clr/ui": "5.5.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^16.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^19.0.0",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "1.0.8",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.19",
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "^0.1102.19",
    "@angular/cli": "11.2.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.14",
    "@types/node": "12.11.1",
    "acorn": "^8.7.1",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.1",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.1.5",
    "webpack": "^4.32.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  }
}
```

'ɵmod' property: what does this mean?  Is there experimental library/code?
Am I using some incompatible version of libraries?
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: It seems that you're using one or more libs that are not compatible with Angular 11.

Comment: Please point out one or more offending lib. That would help me a lot. I've been trying to reduce one by one, and then added as required by the 'ng build'.  Not sure this is the right way because sometimes I found myself going in circles...

Comment: One of those could be the problem: "@cds/core": "5.0.0",
    "@clr/angular": "5.5.3",
    "@clr/icons": "12.0.12",
    "@clr/ui": "5.5.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^16.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^19.0.0",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "1.0.8",

Comment: problem solved, please refer to the following answer: 
 
 
 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464062/unexpected-value-decoratorfactory-imported-by-the-module-tempmodule